# Pass id parameter into imported class in Django

Tags: python, django

In Django I have a function based view responsible of printing the details (actually only the name) of all the registered users on a pdf file.

```
def test_pdf(request, id):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="My Users.pdf"'

    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    report = MyPrint(buffer, 'Letter', id)
    pdf = report.print_users()

    response.write(pdf)
    return response
```

This function works because I imported in the views.py file a class I built in another file, responsible of drawing the pdf, MyPrint:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_CENTER
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class MyPrint:
    def __init__(self, buffer, pagesize):
        self.buffer = buffer
        if pagesize == 'A4':
            self.pagesize = A4
        elif pagesize == 'Letter':
            self.pagesize = letter
            self.width, self.height = self.pagesize
    def print_users(self):
        buffer = self.buffer
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer,
        rightMargin=72,
        leftMargin=72,
        topMargin=72,
        bottomMargin=72,
        pagesize=self.pagesize)
        # Our container for 'Flowable' objects
        elements = []

        # A large collection of style sheets pre-made for us
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='centered', alignment=TA_CENTER))

        # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
        # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
        users = User.objects.all()
        elements.append(Paragraph('My User Names', styles['Heading1']))
        for i, user in enumerate(users):
            elements.append(Paragraph(user.get_full_name(), styles['Normal']))

        doc.build(elements)

        # Get the value of the BytesIO buffer and write it to the response.
        pdf = buffer.getvalue()
        buffer.close()
        return pdf
```

Now, How can I make the function and the class specific to a user if I pass in the relative pk into the function? Apart from updating the urlpattern, should I pass the id into the class and / or into the function?

Comment: What is `id` in `test_pdf`?

Comment: well I did not define it...because I thought it would define itself in the MyPrint class

Comment: You have to explain what you want to do. MyPrint is a plain python class so if you want to pass it a specific user when initializing, add it as parameter to your —init— method. I would pass the user object, not an id btw. So your view can handle the case when an id is incorrect (doesn’t match a user)

Comment: so, you would do __init__(self, buffer, pagesize, id) and then self.id = User.objects.get(id=id)? I tried it did not work...the id must be the one passed in the function which is in the file view.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the existing function work with one or more users, and continue to work if you don't pass in an `id`, I think the simplest way of changing it would be as follows:

```
def print_users(self, id=None):
        buffer = self.buffer
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer,
        rightMargin=72,
        leftMargin=72,
        topMargin=72,
        bottomMargin=72,
        pagesize=self.pagesize)
        # Our container for 'Flowable' objects
        elements = []

        # A large collection of style sheets pre-made for us
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='centered', alignment=TA_CENTER))

        # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
        # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
        users = User.objects.all()
        if id:
            users = users.filter(id__in=id)
        elements.append(Paragraph('My User Names', styles['Heading1']))
        for i, user in enumerate(users):
            elements.append(Paragraph(user.get_full_name(), styles['Normal']))

        doc.build(elements)

        # Get the value of the BytesIO buffer and write it to the response.
        pdf = buffer.getvalue()
        buffer.close()
        return pdf
```

Then change how you call it to:

```
report = MyPrint(buffer, 'Letter')
pdf = report.print_users(id)
```

or, if you want to print *all* users, just call it as:

```
report = MyPrint(buffer, 'Letter')
pdf = report.print_users()
```

Comment: Works beautifully! I did not understand the id=None though, why did you do that?

Comment: It's a default argument. It means that if you don't pass `id`, it will default to a value of `None`. Check out the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. But in order to print all user / single user I need anyway to create two functions in the view, right? Because otherwise if I do not pass any id argument django throws an exception based on the urlpattern I declared in the urls.py (<int:id>/testpdf)

Comment: You can add a default argument to the view as well. Then you'd only need to have two urls, both pointing to the same view. See [Specifying defaults for view arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments)

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering, last question: so there will be in the urlpatterns one instance accepting parameter `<int:id>/testpdf` and one without 
 parameters `/testpdf`. Then in the class I need to specify the `else:` case in case no `id` is passed. Lastly, the `pdf = report.print_users(id)` should stay like this? no need of calling the one without argument `pdf = report.print_users()`?

Comment: Exactly. If you add a default argument to the view, there's no need for (but also no harm in having) the default argument in the class method.